# Actualizar categoria en el campo selected PDO

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

Tengo el siguiente código pero al cambiar de categoría no me actualiza el campo.
Lo curioso es que los demás campos si me los actualiza, excepto el de la categoría.
Gracias de antemano.

***Tabla***

```
    <?php 
    include '../../config/conexion.php';
    $query_contactos = $bd->query("SELECT contactos.id_contactos AS id_contactos,contactos.id_categoria AS id_categoria, contactos.nombre AS nombre,contactos.apellido_1 
    as apellido_1,contactos.apellido_2 as apellido_2,contactos.telefono as telefono,
    contactos.email as email,contactos.foto AS foto,categorias.nombre as categoria
    FROM t_contactos AS contactos
    INNER JOIN t_categorias AS categorias ON contactos.id_categoria = categorias.id_categoria");
    $t_contactos = $query_contactos->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    //print_r($t_contactos);
?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../style.css">
        <title>Lista de Contactos</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3 id="mostrar">Lista de Contactos</h3>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>#</td>
                <td>Nombre</td>
                <td>Apellido 1</td>
                <td>Apellido 2</td>
                <td>Teléfono</td>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td>Categoria</td>
                <td>Foto</td>
                <td>Accion 1</td>
                <td>Accion 2</td>
            </tr>
            <?php foreach ($t_contactos as $fila_C) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $fila_C->id_contactos;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila_C->nombre;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila_C->apellido_1;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila_C->apellido_2;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila_C->telefono;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila_C->email;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila_C->categoria;?></td>
                <td><img src='data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($fila_C->foto); ?>'></td>
                
                <td><a href="editar.php?id=<?php echo $fila_C->id_contactos;?>&id_categoria=<?php echo $fila_C->id_categoria;?>">Editar</a></td>
                <td><a href="../procesos/tabla_contactos/eliminarProceso.php?id=<?php echo $fila_C->id_contactos;?>">Eliminar</a></td>
                
            <?php } ?>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

***Formulario***

```
 <?php
    include '../../config/Conexion.php';
    
    //print_r($_GET);
    
    if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
        header('Location: ../vista_de_contactos/listar_contactos.php');
    }
    
    $id_contactos = $_GET['id'];
    $id_categoria = $_GET['id_categoria'];
    
    try {
        $query_contactos = $bd->prepare("SELECT * FROM t_contactos WHERE id_contactos = ? ORDER BY id_contactos;");
        $query_contactos->execute([$id_contactos]);
        $t_contactos = $query_contactos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        //print_r($t_contacto);
    } catch (PDOException $eContacto) {
        echo "Error en la sentencia <br>" . $eContacto->getMessage();
    }
    
    try {
    
        $query_categorias = $bd->prepare("SELECT * FROM t_categorias ORDER BY id_categoria;");
        $query_categorias->execute();
        $t_categorias = $query_categorias->fetchAll();
    } catch (PDOException $eCategorias) {
        echo "Error en la sentencia <br>" . $eCategorias->getMessage();
    }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../style.css">
        <title>Editar Contactos</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <h3 class="insertar">Editar Contactos</h3>
        <form method="POST" action="../procesos/tabla_contactos/editarProceso.php" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            Categorias
            <select name="id_categoria">
                <?php
                foreach ($t_categorias as  $fila_C) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $fila_C["id_categoria"] . '"';
    
                    if ($id_categoria == $fila_C["id_categoria"]) {
                        echo 'selected';
                    }
                    echo '>' . $fila_C["nombre"] . '</option>';
                }
                ?>
    
            </select> 
    
            <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" name="nombre" value="<?php echo $t_contactos->nombre; ?>">
    
            <label for="apellido_1">apellido 1</label>
            <input type="text" name="apellido_1" value="<?php echo $t_contactos->apellido_1; ?>">
    
            <label for="apellido_2">Apellido 2</label>
            <input type="text" name="apellido_2" value="<?php echo $t_contactos->apellido_2; ?>">
    
            <label for="telefono">Telefono</label>
            <input type="text" name="telefono" value="<?php echo $t_contactos->telefono; ?>">
    
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $t_contactos->email; ?>">
    
            <label for="imagen">Foto</label>
            <input type="file" name="foto" size="20" value="<img src='data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($t_contactos->foto); ?>'>"> 
    
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $t_contactos->id_contactos;?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="id_usuarios" value="<?php echo $t_contactos->id_usuarios;?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="id_categoria" value="<?php echo $t_contactos->id_categoria;?>">
            
            <input type="submit" value="Actualizar Contacto">
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

***Proceso***

```
<?php 
     include '../../../config/Conexion.php';
    //print_r($_POST);
    if(!isset($_POST['id'])){
        header('Location: ../vista_de_contactos/listar_contactos.php');
        //print_r($_POST);
    }
    
    try {
        $id_contactos = $_POST['id'];
        $id_categoria = $_POST['id_categoria'];
        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
        $apellido_1 = $_POST['apellido_1'];
        $apellido_2 = $_POST['apellido_2'];
        $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $categoria = $_POST['nombre'];
        //$foto = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name']));

        $query_actualizar = $bd->prepare("UPDATE t_contactos SET id_categoria = ?,nombre = ?, apellido_1 = ?, apellido_2 = ?, telefono = ?, email = ?, nombre = ?  
        WHERE id_contactos = ?;");
        $resultado = $query_actualizar->execute([$id_categoria,$nombre,$apellido_1,$apellido_2,$telefono,$email,$categoria,$id_contactos]);

        if($resultado === true){
            header('Location: ../../vista_de_contactos/listar_contactos.php'); 
        }
    } catch (PDOException $eMostrarUP) {
        echo "Error al ejecutar la sentencia actualizar ".$eMostrarUP->getMessage();

    }
```

***Resultado esperado***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: A primera vista se ve todo bien, prueba dando click derecho en tu select, inspeccionar, y fija que cambie el value.

Comment: te he puesto un par de fotos con la bbdd correspondiente y sus categorías JOSE MORIANO un saludo, lo que creo que tengo mal es el update del mismo, sería cuestión de hacerla bien o de corregirla y no se si esta del todo bien. Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Eres consciente de que le diste el mismo `name` a dos elementos? El `select` y uno de tus `input` se llaman ambos `id_categoria`. Puede que el problema esté ahí. Si no es eso, te recomiendo que nos digas exactamente dónde está el problema y que nos digas también qué depuraciones has hecho y con qué resultados (eso sirve más que tantas imágenes). La pregunta está planteada de una forma demasiado difusa y habría que leerla unas 10 veces para ver si luego uno puede adivinar lo que quieres hacer. Muchas el principal problema es no saber explicar el propio problema.

Comment: Cuando hablo de depurar me refiero por ejemplo a que nos muestres un `var_dump` del elemento que usas para obtener los datos con los cuales armas tu sentencia `UPDATE` que es la que dices que está fallando.

Comment: precisamente tenia el mismo name que en el input, ahora paso un var_dump de la consulta con los datos introducidos

Comment: Este es el resultado de la consulta al meter los datos :

Array ( [seleccionar_C] => 2 [nombre] => Pepooo [apellido_1] => pep [apellido_2] => pep [telefono] => 666-999-001 [email] => admin@gmail.com [id] => 1 [id_usuarios] => 1 [id_categoria] => 1 ) object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(141) "UPDATE t_contactos SET id_categoria = ?,nombre = ?, apellido_1 = ?, apellido_2 = ?, telefono = ?, email = ? WHERE id_contactos = ?;" }